# Simics Eclipse not found. Please install package 1001

Tags: simics

I downloaded Intel-Simics-Public-Release-Preview and have it installed on a CentOS 8.4 box, I went to `my-simics-project-1` directory, there is a `simics-eclipse`, but when I run it, it reports an error: `Simics Eclipse not found. Please install package 1001.`.

Is that because the preview version doesn't contains that package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted on [Intel website](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/simics-simulator.html),

> The Eclipse* IDE for Simics® software GUI is not included in the public Simics simulator release.