# Is there a way to see the raw bytes in disassembly view?

Tags: simics

Is there a way to see the raw bytes of assembly instructions in the disassembly view? (One of the downsides of the HTML documentation is that it doesn't seem to be searchable?)

Also, is Simics Eclipse even an option for the free preview? (It seems like it maybe the Eclipse view could show raw bytes.) I don't see it listed in the base packages.

Comment: Searchable HTML docs should be coming in the next release of public Simics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the CLI, there is a "disassemble-settings", which can turn on to show OpCode

```
disassemble-settings opcode = on
```

[image: Showing OpCode in Disassemble]

Comment: Regarding Eclipse, it is not part of free public release. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68052006/simics-eclipse-not-found-please-install-package-1001